# gerar um log dos Usuarios no C#

Tags: c#

Pessoal meu projeto da faculdade estou fazendo em C# windowsform e gostaria de gerar um logo que quando um usuário incluir, excluir, alterar em qualquer form gere um log onde eu poderei criar um forme de log de todos os usuário que fizer qualquer evento.

em cada form criei um userConectado que me traz do menu e passo como parâmetro para frente sei quem está executando o form no momento

nem sei por onde começar.

aagradeço

Comment: Como está sua camada de dados? Você usa Entity Framework? Se não, você que escreveu a camada de dados?

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode usar o código abaixo. Não é muito completo mas já cumpre o objetivo.

```
namespace LogUtils
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading;

    public class LogWriter
    {
        // cria um modelo de dados para armazenar as informações de log. Como ele só será usado nesta classe pode ser definido dentro dela como interno.
        internal class LogEntry
        {
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public string UserLogin { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
        }
        // Singleton, usado para acesso as funcionalidade dessa classe. Garante que só exista uma instancia por aplicação.
        private static LogWriter instance;
        public static LogWriter Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                    instance = new LogWriter();
                return instance;
            }
        }
        // final da declaração do singleton

        private Queue<LogEntry> LogPool;
        private Thread thread;
        //Armazena a pasta atual da aplicação
        private string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Replace("file:\\", "");

        public LogWriter()
        {
            // Cria a fila de entradas de log
            LogPool = new Queue<LogEntry>();
            // Cria a thread responsável por gravar log no arquivo  
            thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteOnDisk));

            thread.Start();
        }
        // Tarefa a ser executada pela thread
        private void WriteOnDisk()
        {
            while (true) // executa infinitamente
            {
                if (LogPool.Count > 0) // verfica se existem logs para gravar
                {
                    LogEntry entry = LogPool.Dequeue(); // retira a entrada de log da fila.
                    //Formata o caminho para o armazenamento do arquivo de log
                    string finalPath = Path.Combine(path, "Logs", entry.Date.Year.ToString(), entry.Date.Month.ToString(), entry.Date.Day.ToString() + ".log");
                    //cria a pasta caso ela não exista.
                    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(finalPath)))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(finalPath));

                    //grava o log
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(finalPath))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}", entry.Date, entry.UserLogin, entry.Message));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void WriteLog(string userLogin, string message)
        {
            //Cria um objeto do tipo LogEntry
            LogEntry entry = new LogEntry { Date = DateTime.Now, UserLogin = userLogin, Message = message };
            //Adiciona entrada na fila
            LogPool.Enqueue(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Copie e cole-o em um novo arquivo.cs. Para usa-lo chame a função abaixo logo após a execução das tarefas de seu sistema:

```
LogUtils.LogWriter.Instance.WriteLog(NOME_USUARIO, MENSAGEM);
```

Atenção, nunca instancie esta classe. Sempre acesse-a da forma mostrada acima.

Por exemplo:

```
LogUtils.LogWriter.Instance.WriteLog(login, "O usuário" + login + "alterou o registro);
```

A classe utiliza uma thread exclusiva para gerenciar o arquivo de log. Esta classe serve tanto para projetos windows forms, quanto para WPF e ASP.NET.

Espero ter ajudado.

Caso tenha gostado da resposta não esqueça de aumentar a pontuação da mesma. Se a resposta resolveu seu problem, defina a pergunta como resolvida. Isso ajuda outras pessoas que procuram pelo mesmo tema. Obrigado.

Comment: Repare que estou usando uma thread para efetuar a gravação. Isso cria uma tarefa isolada, que pode até ser processada em outro núcleo do processador, rodando em segundo plano na sua aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Cria uma classe, por exemplo `Historico`.

Nela as propriedades `UsuarioAlterou`, `DataHora`, `Tela`, `Observacao`.

Crie o método `Salvar()`

Toda vez que você for persistir alguma entidade, você chama esse método `Salvar()`